# There is a problem with reading this code.How to read this?

Tags: c++, c

What does typedef in this case?

```
typedef void(*sfc_funcptr_t)();
sfc_funcptr_t* const func_src = (sfc_funcptr_t*)interfaces;
```

Comment: https://cdecl.org

Comment: Choose one language

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> typedef void(*sfc_funcptr_t)();
> ```

In C `sfc_funcptr_t` is type of "pointer to function returning void and accepting an unspecified, but fixed, number of arguments with unspecified, but fixed, types" (I don't know C++ ... I suspect it might be different)

> ```
> sfc_funcptr_t* const func_src = (sfc_funcptr_t*)interfaces;
> ```

Create and initialize `func_src` as a pointer to (the function) `interfaces`

Comment: In C++, the meaning of `()` (for function parameters) has changed. In C++ this is a _pointer to function returning void and accepting **no** arguments_.

Comment: There is one additional layer of indirection there; possibly `interfaces` is an array of interfaces (pointers to functions).

Comment: @anatolyg, if `interface` would be `sfc_functptr_t[1]` it would decay to `void(**sfc_funcptr_t)()` and thus the cast would be an error.